# Confusion Matrix just showing the first row and the second row is 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, confusion-matrix, resnet

i am using the resnet50 pretrained model, and when the model.fit is done i'm checking the confussion matrix but i got this kind of output, what could be the problem?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import numpy as np

#Confution Matrix and Classification Report
Y_pred = xception.predict(test_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
conf_mtx = confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred)
print(conf_mtx)
```

the result is

```
65/65 [==============================] - 31s 465ms/step
Confusion Matrix
[[1050    0]
 [1000    0]]
```

the dataset i used have 2 folder, train and test and each folder have 2 subfolder. from my understanding from that confussion matrix is the model succesfully predict 1 classes only, is it?

Comment: so it's predicting the same class for all inputs... issue with the data? is the network too simple and can't learn? is the loss function broken? how do loss and accuracy progress during training?